# How to retrieve from Ensembl of a gene's start and end values on a chromosome

Tags: r

Suppose I have a gene called "Tlr6" (see below picture), I am wondering how in R I can retrieve the start and end values of the gene on the chromosome? For instance in the picture, the start value is 64952031 and the end value is 64960097.

The URL of the picture is [here](http://useast.ensembl.org/Mus_musculus/Gene/Summary?db=core;g=ENSMUSG00000051498;r=5:64952031-64960097).
Here the gene name is `Tlr6` and the Ensembl ID is `ENSMUSG00000051498`. Can I use these information to read the start and end values into R?

[image]

Comment: Please post a piece of data not just a (useless) picture.

Comment: I added some elements and hope it will be helpful.

Comment: ok, you have this `ENSMUSG00000051498` (a character string I suppose), what do you want to extract?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `biomaRt` package from `Bioconductor` to do this:

```
#skip this if the package is already installed
source("http://bioconductor.org/biocLite.R")
biocLite("biomaRt")

library(biomaRt)
#select the ensembl mouse dataset
ensembl <- useMart("ensembl", dataset="mmusculus_gene_ensembl")


getBM(attributes=c("ensembl_gene_id","start_position","end_position"),
  filters="ensembl_gene_id",values = "ENSMUSG00000051498",mart=ensembl)
```

More info about the package [here](http://www.bioconductor.org/packages/release/bioc/vignettes/biomaRt/inst/doc/biomaRt.pdf).

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you mean?

```
> Tlr6 <- "64.952.031-64.960.097"
> c(gsub("\\.", "", substr(Tlr6, 1, 10)), gsub("\\.", "", substr(Tlr6, 12, 21)))
[1] "64952031" "64960097"
```

Or are you asking about how to scrape that initial value from the web page as well?